# How to see Google Calendar from GMail?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

My GMail used to have a side-widget that showed my upcoming Google Calendar events.  A few months ago they removed it because (???).  Now the only way to see my upcoming events is to manually view my calendar, which is a huge pain.

Is there any way to re-enable it, or add something with similar functionality?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *(following your [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145676/how-to-see-google-calendar-from-gmail/145680?noredirect=1#comment133166_145680))*

> *Hmm, then I can't find it anywhere. My Gmail looks nothing like that screenshot*

You probably have your `Side Panel` hidden.
Go to the **bottom right corner** and unhide it.

[image: Gmail Side Panel]

---

Original answer

You mentioned:

> GMail used to have a side-widget that showed my upcoming Google Calendar events...
> ...any way to re-enable it, or add **something with similar functionality**?

You can still see your upcoming events once you click on the little calendar icon on the top right corner of your screen and choose `Schedule`

[image: View future/upcoming Google Calendar events from Gmail]

Comment: That's in the calendar app, not gmail

Comment: *"That's in the calendar app, not gmail"* No. **What you see is a screenshot form GMail**.

Comment: Hmm, then I can't find it anywhere. My Gmail looks nothing like that screenshot

Comment: Have you tried the edited answer? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.